# Modelling the rate of mass loss of liquid in a hemispherical bowl

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering how to model the rate of mass loss of liquid as it evaporates from a hemispherical bowl. Assuming that the rate of change of volume is proportional to the exposed surface area, I know that as the liquid evaporates, the radius of exposure decreases (the top circle gets smaller).

I thought that the radius would change with this:$$\frac{dV}{dt} = -kA $$
$$\frac{d(\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3)}{dt} = -k\pi r^2$$
$$r = - \frac{1}{2}kt + c$$

However I am not sure how to continue and arrive at a final equation for $ \frac{dV}{dt}$ to plug in to:
$$\frac{dm}{dt} = \rho \frac{dV}{dt}$$
to find the final relationship for the rate of mass loss.

Thanks

Comment: I think you've calculated the volume of the spherical cap incorrectly.

Comment: You already found $r(t)$ and $m$ is $\rho \frac{2}{3} \pi r^3$.
If you want an equation on $V$ you can notice that $$A=\pi \left(\frac{3}{2 \pi} V \right)^\frac{2}{3}$$